# Layout doesn't work inside onTouch()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am creating an Activity with two ImageViews.

The first ImageView occupies a part of the screen on startup and I want to show the other ImageView, whose content is a crop around the region where I touch the first Image and on TOP of it.

Class:

```
public class DetectEyesActivity extends Activity  implements OnTouchListener {  
private ImageView imgView;
private Bitmap imgBitmap;

private ImageView touchView2;
private Bitmap temp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.detecteyeslayout);

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    byte[] image = intent.getByteArrayExtra("Image");

    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detectImageView1);
    touchView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detectImageView2);

    imgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);   

    temp = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgBitmap, 200, 200, 200, 200);
    //touchView2.setImageBitmap(temp);

    imgView.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int y = (int)event.getY();
    int x = (int)event.getX();

    temp = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgBitmap, 200,200, 200, 200);
    touchView2.setImageBitmap(temp);
    touchView2.setVisibility(0);
    touchView2.bringToFront();
    touchView2.layout(x-200, y-200, x-30, y-30);

    return true;
}
```

}

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detectImageView1"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detectImageView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But when I call

```
touchView2.setImageBitmap(temp);
```

Inside onTouch() the view is drawn below the initial image on the layout. But if I call it inside onCreate() it is drawn on top of the initial image?

Why does this happens, and how I can I solve this problem?

Comment: What layout type are the views contained in?  The question is tagged with `LinearLayout`, but the XML you've provided is only for the two images.

Comment: forgive me... its updated now

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want one of your images overlayed on the other.  LinearLayouts display their children in either a horizontal or vertical line.  This is not a good ViewGroup to use for your case, as it does not allow multiple children to occupy the same space.  I'd try either a Relative or Frame Layout.

Also, you have the second image's visibility set to `gone` initially, so it's not that the first image is being drawn over it, but that the second image just isn't being drawn at all until you call `setVisibility` in your onTouch.